# Problems building very basic application that uses Samsung S Pen SDK 2.3

Tags: java, android

I'm not experienced in Android and I'm trying to create a very simple application using Samsung S-Pen SDK 2.3. I'm following [this tutorial](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/S-Pen-SDK-2-2-5-Tutorial) from Samsung developers website. When I implement the most basic example I get the following error.

```
WARNING: Could not load libjni_secime natives
No implementation found for native Lcom/bst/HwBeautify/BeautifyNative;.nativeCBInitEngine:()I
threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a242a0)
...

FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1829
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.bst.HwBeautify.BeautifyNative.nativeCBInitEngine:()
at com.bst.HwBeautify.BeautifyNative.nativeCBInitEngine(Native Method)
at com.bst.HwBeautify.BeautifyNative.cbInitEngine(SourceFile:107)
at com.bst.HwBeautify.BeautifyManager.b(SourceFile:87)
at com.bst.HwBeautify.BeautifyManager.a(SourceFile:85)
at com.bst.HwBeautify.BeautifyManager$1.run(SourceFile:64)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
...
S-Canvas is not created yet. Call "changeModeTo" in onInitialized() of SCanvasInitializeListener or call it after onInitialized() SCanvasLayout is up to been initailized
... No implementation found for native Lcom/bst/HwBeautify/BeautifyNative;.nativeCBInitEngine:()I threadid=16: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a242a0)
```

**Here the whole code for the activity that is supposed to initialize canvas:**

```
package com.example.canvastest;

import com.samsung.spensdk.SCanvasView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class CanvasSpace extends Activity {


    private Context mContext;
    private RelativeLayout mCanvasContainer;
    private SCanvasView mSCanvas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_canvas_space);

        mContext = this;

        mCanvasContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.canvas_container);
        mSCanvas = new SCanvasView(mContext);

        mCanvasContainer.addView(mSCanvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.canvas_space, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

**And here is my layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".CanvasSpace" >

    <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/canvas_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">        
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What concerns me is this very weird `S_Pen_SDK2.3` folder structure. Instead of normal directories I have filenames with paths (705 items).

[image: SDK Folder]

I have never seen anything like this. Why would anybody do something like this? Are there any benefits of having folder structured like this?
Anyways, I follow the tutorial, I reference the library and include files in `armeabi` folder as specified. 
**Here is the view of my package explorer:**

[image: Package explorer]

I searched the web and I found [a thread](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SPenSDK&messageId=223509) on Samsung developers that addresses this problem but it doesn't help in my case. What I tried so far was to remove those paths before filenames in `armeabi` folder but that didn't help. That would help me very much if somebody gave me some hints of how do I get it to work. I included so much obvious code and screenshots to make it perfectly clear what do I have in my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The library is imported in the wrong way, that's why you get the exception.

Copy the `libspen23.jar` and also the whole `armeabi` directory to the `libs`.

It should looks like this:

```
libs  
   armeabi
      lib* (all .so files)
   libspen23.jar
```

Look at the samples provided with the S Pen SDK 2.3, which shows how to properly import the library.

Comment: Aaaa. I'm so ashamed now. However, when I read it again its not that clear in the tutorial that `armeabi` folder should be in `libs` directory. Thank you so much!